# How to use HTML date type with Django and HTMX

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, htmx

I am trying to get date from a picker and trigger an hx-get when the date is changed.  The code below produces and text input field with a datepicker pop up. When I pop up the datepicker and change the date, the hx-get is not triggered. If I then click in the text input area the hx-get is triggered with the picked date.  So how do I get the trigger to activate when I select the date from the picker?

I tried both the TextInput and DAteInput widgets but they both act the same way.  I played a bit with django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus but found it did not work well with my forms which use both HTMX and Crispy forms helper layouts.

Thanks

```
    datedue = forms.DateField(initial=timezone.now().date(),
                              label="On or before",
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date',
                                    'hx-get': reverse_lazy('change-priority'),
                                    'hx-target': '#tasklist',
                                    'hx-include': '[name="priority"], [name="status"],[name="assigned"], [name="iscomplete"]',
                                    'hx-trigger': 'click change'
                                    })
                                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the events with a [comma](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/).

```
datedue = forms.DateField(initial=timezone.now().date(),
                          label="On or before",
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date',
                                'hx-get': reverse_lazy('change-priority'),
                                'hx-target': '#tasklist',
                                'hx-include': '[name="priority"], [name="status"],[name="assigned"], [name="iscomplete"]',
                                'hx-trigger': 'click, change'
                                })
                            )
```

The space separator is used for event modifiers, e.g. `change delay:1s`.

Comment: Ouch. Sometimes it's the little things that get you!  Thanks